# Finding a partial derivative of the difference of convex functions that involves limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

Suppose that we have a function $g$ defined as
$$
g(x,\alpha) = \lim_{\alpha\to +\infty} \{f(k - \alpha x) - f(-\alpha x)\} :=\lim_{\alpha\to +\infty} F_\alpha(x)
$$
with $f$ being a convex function and $k$ a constant. The goal is to find $\frac{\partial g(x,\alpha)}{\partial x}$ (maybe an approximate one w.r.t $f'$ or $\nabla f$). Can we argue something about uniform convergence using convexity so that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \lim_{\alpha\to \infty} F_\alpha(x) = \lim_{\alpha\to\infty} \frac{\partial F_\alpha(x)}{\partial x} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Any alternative approaches not using equation (1) are also welcome. The original problem that I have is with multivariables (i.e., $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$) but I want to start with the simple case.

Comment: Do you mean $g(x)$ rather than $g(x, \alpha)$?

Comment: @RiverLi So we have $g$ as a function of two variables $x$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: After taking limit, $\alpha$ disappears?

Comment: So, $g(x) = \lim_{\alpha\to +\infty} F_\alpha(x)$. You want $g'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}  \lim_{\alpha\to +\infty} F_\alpha(x) = \lim_{\alpha\to +\infty} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} F_\alpha(x) $.

Comment: @RiverLi Can't tell much about the limiting behaviour of $\alpha$ (not even sure whether or not it will disappear) but we do want to deal with equations that you wrote down.  I defined $F_\alpha(x)$ because the function itself will depend on each value of $\alpha$. The problem comes from the convex analysis literature that I'm working on, so sorry if it caused any confusion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I mean $g(x) = \lim_{\alpha\to +\infty} F_\alpha(x)$ rather than $g(x, \alpha) = \lim_{\alpha\to +\infty} F_\alpha(x)$. For example, $f(x) = \ln(1 + \mathrm{e}^{-x})$. Then $\lim_{\alpha\to +\infty} F_\alpha(x) = -1$ (taking limit as $\alpha\to \infty$, the limit does not contain $\alpha$, or $\alpha$ disappears). Do you have any example of $f(x)$ in the literature?

Comment: @RiverLi In the literature $f(x) = \max_{w\in S} w^T x$ where $S$ is a compact and convex set (you can think of it as a simple unit sphere or a polyhedron)

Comment: So you want to prove that $\frac{\partial }{\partial x} [\max_{w\in S} w^T (k - \alpha x) - \max_{w\in S} w^T (-\alpha x)]$ converges uniformly?

Answer (score 1):

First, if the equation (1) is well-defined. $g(x,\alpha)$ should be $g(x)$, which is independent of $\alpha$.

Second, to exchange derivative and limit:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}F_\alpha(x)=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}F_{\alpha}(x),
$$
To make this exchange work, a common conclusion is that if $F_\alpha(x)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}F_{\alpha}(x)$ converge locally uniformly convergence in $x$ when $\alpha\rightarrow\infty$, then we can do the exchange. In general, I don't see how to make use of convexity here.

For your question from the literature (in your comments), assume $k\neq \vec{0}$. when S is a sphere ($|x|<1$), we can see
$$
F_\alpha(x)=|k-\alpha x|-|\alpha x|\,,
$$
which implies
$$\tag{1}
F_{\infty}(x)=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}F_{\alpha}(x)=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|k-\alpha x|^2-|\alpha x|^2}{|k-\alpha x|+|\alpha x|}=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|k|^2-2\alpha k\cdot x}{|k-\alpha x|+|\alpha x|}=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{|k|^2}{\alpha}-2k\cdot x}{\frac{|k-\alpha x|+|\alpha x|}{\alpha}}=-k\cdot \frac{x}{|x|}\,.
$$
Therefore, it's obvious that $F_{\infty}(x)$ is differentiable at $x\neq \vec{0}$ and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}F_{\infty}(x)=-\frac{k}{|x|}-\frac{(k\cdot x)x}{|x|^3},\quad x\neq \vec{0}
$$
Then we go back to $F_{\alpha}(x)$. Fisrt, $F_{\alpha}(x)$ is differential at $x\neq \vec{0}$ and $x\neq \frac{k}{\alpha}$. This implies when $x\neq \vec{0}$, when $\alpha$ is large enough, $F_{\alpha}(x)$ is always differentiable. Furthermore,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial_x} F_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{-\alpha(k-\alpha x)}{|k-\alpha x|}-\frac{|\alpha| x}{|x|}
$$
It's easy to verify that
$$\tag{2}
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial_x} F_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{-\alpha(k-\alpha x)}{|k-\alpha x|}-\frac{|\alpha| x}{|x|}=-\frac{k}{|x|}-\frac{(k\cdot x)x}{|x|^3},\quad x\neq \vec{0}\,.
$$
Therefore, the derivative and limit can exchange in this case.

In this case, it's easy to check that the convergence in (1) and (2) is locally uniformly when $x\neq 0$.

For general convex set $S$, we can prove
$$
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}F_\alpha(x)=\max_{w\in S_x}w^\top k\,,
$$
where $S_x=\mathrm{argmax}_{w\in S}-w^\top x$. But this convergence might not be locally uniformly at some particular point even $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}F_\alpha(x_0)$ exists. For example, consider $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $S=[-1,1]\times \mathbb{R}$, $k=(1/2,1/2)$, then we can see that
$$
\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}F_\alpha(x)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&-\frac{1}{2},\quad x_{[1]}>0 \\
&\frac{1}{2},\quad x_{[1]}\leq 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
where $x_{[1]}$ is the first component of $x$. Because $F_\alpha(x)$ is continuous, the convergence is not locally uniformly around $x_0=(0,x_{[2]})$ for any $x_{[2]}\in\mathbb{R}$.